# Atlas with different projections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, atlas

I have created an atlas -- i.e. a map with a layer defining some regions of interest -- in QGIS. I can render maps of each region using the "atlas" feature of the print composer, but I want to show different regions with different projections. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 years later... I just had the same problem

Make a field for CRS in your atlas coverage layer and fill it with the desired CRS. You need to write in form like 'EPSG: 3576' in the field. Than use the data defined override > Edit > [Name of field in Attribute Table]

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible at the moment. Maps within the composer will always use the same projection as the main map canvas.